# How to get the result of zoom.translate() without altering the sensibility of panning?

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I have a D3.js draw in a svg and I want to be able to pan and zoom on it. I also want a rectangle to be drawn around the initial window. I want the rectangle to become smaller as I zoom out, larger as I zoom in and to move normally as I pan around. Usual stuff.

I also want to be able to redraw the rectangle to make it fit again the actual window (so it will be smaller than the first if I zoomed in between the redraw for example). I didn't included this part in the code example but it explains why I need a way to get the zoom properties.

To properly trace the rectangle I found the zoom.translate() and zoom.scale() property, supposed to give me the parameters I need to calculate the coordinates of the rectangle's parts. However since I added this part to my code the panning sensibility became to shift as I zoom in and out: The more I zoom in, the less sensible is the panning, and the more I zoom out the more sensible it becomes.

In my mind, zoom.translate() and zoom.scale() were only supposed to fetch the parameters, not to change the way zooming and panning work, how can I fix that?

I also have inexplicably a rectangle that doesn't fit the window: it is a bit larger and shorter.

Here my piece of code:

```
var svg;
var map;
var zoom;
var graph = d3.select("#graph");

zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scale(1)
    .on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    });
svg = graph.append("svg")
    .attr("width",window.innerWidth)
    .attr("height",window.innerHeight)
    .call(zoom);
map = svg.append("g");
```

Here is the acquisition of the rectangle's coordinates:

```
var w_b = {
    x_min: (0 - zoom.translate()[0])/zoom.scale(),
    x_max: (svg.attr("width") - zoom.translate()[0])/zoom.scale(),
    y_min: (0 - zoom.translate()[1])/zoom.scale(),
    y_max: (svg.attr("height") - zoom.translate()[1])/zoom.scale()
```

And here is the drawing of the rectangle:

```
map.selectAll("line").remove();
map.append("line").attr("x1", w_b['x_min']).attr("x2", w_b['x_max']).attr("y1", w_b['y_min']).attr("y2", w_b['y_min'])
    .attr("stroke-width", 1).attr("stroke", "black");
map.append("line").attr("x1", w_b['x_min']).attr("x2", w_b['x_max']).attr("y1", w_b['y_max']).attr("y2", w_b['y_max'])
    .attr("stroke-width", 1).attr("stroke", "black");
map.append("line").attr("x1", w_b['x_min']).attr("x2", w_b['x_min']).attr("y1", w_b['y_min']).attr("y2", w_b['y_max'])
    .attr("stroke-width", 1).attr("stroke", "black");
map.append("line").attr("x1", w_b['x_max']).attr("x2", w_b['x_max']).attr("y1", w_b['y_min']).attr("y2", w_b['y_max'])
    .attr("stroke-width", 1).attr("stroke", "black");
```

As a bonus question, this doesn't work at all on Chrome, any idea about what it could be ?

Answer (score 0):

To work correctly, the zoom must be defined like this:

```
zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scale(1)
    .on("zoom", function () {
        map.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    });
```

Notice the "map.attr" instead of "svg.attr".
However it doesn't solve the issues about the size of the window and the fact it's not working on Chrome.